# Install python-wxgtk2.8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.04, ppa

Does anybody know how to install `python-wxgtk2.8` on Ubuntu 16.04?

Is needed for ride (robot framework)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `python-wxgtk2.8` does not exist in the Ubuntu 16.04 repositories, but `python-wxgtk3.0` does. Maybe you want to try `sudo apt install python-wxgtk3.0` instead?

Comment: @edwinksl RIDE doesn't work with wxpython newer than 2.8.

Comment: @Ubuntovod Good to know, that's useful information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Take a turn, you are in the wrong direction!**

The correct way is move on with newer release. But for side packages like this one, you can always install builds from older releases. If APT didn't raise any unmet dependencies.

A rule that may help you in future with other packages: See `python-wxgtk2.8`, The *upstream version* `2.8` is part of *Debian package name*. Ubuntu (dpkg/apt) allows installation of multiple copies of a package if they don't have same package name.

Tested on VBox with Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Add needed repository and update package list

   ```
    echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wily-copies.list
    sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install it

   ```
    sudo apt install python-wxgtk2.8
   ```
3. Remove repository entry and update package list again

   ```
    sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wily-copies.list
    sudo apt update
   ```

**Note:**

Following this method on large scale can lead to [unmet dependency hell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa). So keep in mind this is similar to PPA's. To solve issues with following packages, purge them:

```
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
libgstreamer0.10-0
libwxbase2.8-0
libwxgtk-media2.8-0
libwxgtk2.8-0
python-wxgtk2.8
python-wxversion
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. Indeed i was searching for the proper repository to add but without success and thus the question.

1 - step done but step2 asks for the dependencies
and the apt  list --upgradable points to the same dependencies.

Comment: @EftychiaThomaidou, Are they the same list I've already  posted? If so go with step two it's ok, and Not  `apt list --upgradable` and avoid  `apt upgrade` too.

Comment: i've used  **apt-get -f install** to fix the dependency issues.

Answer (score 4):

You can download packages from previous version at http://packages.ubuntu.com/, in this case you need http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-wxgtk2.8.

I usually choose the closest Ubuntu distro version that has the needed packages and download those. It's better to avoid it, but sometimes one can't.

Answer (score 4):

This was able to resolve this problem by doing this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Update the package index:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Install python-wxgtk2.8 deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

Comment: The output is `add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: Try this `apt-get install software-properties-common` to install add-apt-repository tool