# Missing dependencues: python-wxgtk2.8

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, python, dependencies

I'm trying to install tribler and it had missing the missing dependency python-wxgtk2.8. I don't know how to install it.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install ` ?

Comment: yup i've tried that

Comment: then what is the response? any error message or smth?

Comment: That package has been updated to `python-wxgtk3.0`. There a couple of workaround if you do a search. Here's one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789302/install-python-wxgtk2-8-on-ubuntu-16-04  And here's two: https://forum.tribler.org/t/cant-install-tribler-6-5-2-in-ubuntu-16-04-package-python-wxgtk2-8-is-not-installed/3510/7