# How to install the Rubiks Futuro cube suite on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have a Rubik's Futuro Cube and would like to use the desktop suite for customisation and the like.

I have previously had the program and want to install it on my new machine which is running Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there a way I can match the old dependencies to run it?

The download link is [here](http://isle.princip.cz/download/futurocube/sdk_suite/rubiks-futuro-cube.SC1.8.tgz) (Completely virus free, taken directly from the website.).

And [here](http://www.futurocube.com/support/) is the full downloads page.

Comment: As always: 1. Download the application from a trustworthy source. 2. extract the package to a known location `mkdir rubiks; cd rubiks; tar xfvz ../rubiks*cube*.tgz`. 3. Read the manual in the package or on the website. Most times `./configure; make; make install` will do the trick, but you should take care of the decencies of your special program.

Comment: @LupusE While decencies are certainly important, *dependencies* matter even more ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Install a Ubuntu Trusty for the next steps, or read my second answer to visualize a Trusty in Ubuntu Bionic or Debian Strech with LXC (Linux Container).

- Prepare a Workspace. `mkdir -p ~/work/rubiks/; cd ~/work/rubiks/`
- Download the file. `wget http://isle.princip.cz/download/futurocube/sdk_suite/rubiks-futuro-cube.SC1.8.tgz`
- Extract the file. `tar xfvz rubiks-futuro-cube.SC1.8.tgz`
- Go to the folder. `cd rubiks-futuro-cube`
- Read the Documentation. `vim INSTALL.txt`
- Do the steps:

  1. Install dependencies `sudo apt install python ipython python-imaging python-serial python-wxgtk2.8`
  2. Install 64bit compatibility `sudo apt install ia32-libs` (from INSTALL.txt, not longer needed)
  3. change the udev rule
  4. Add your user to the dialout group. `sudo adduser $USER dialout`
  5. Launch the program `./rubiks-futuro-cube`

Comment: Unfortunately the dependencies wont install, meaning the program wont run.

Comment: Great. Now the next step. What part of the whole line isn't going to install (I really hope you've copy and pasted it from the INSTALL.txt, not from my list here!)

Comment: The Answer is: E: Package 'python-wxgtk2.8' has no installation candidate ... But before Mixing up some older sources in my regular anvironment, I'd suggest to install an older ubuntu in a VirtualBox (good USB forwarding) Environment ... Or ask the Developer for port it to python 3.x ... If anyone want to shoot in the foot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/789302/install-python-wxgtk2-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: New approach: `apt install lxc  libvirt0 libpam-cgroup libpam-cgfs bridge-utils` and set `vim /etc/default/lxc-net` and enter **USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"**.  Take allok at packages.ubuntu.com and see the latest version, providing python-wxgtk2.8 is trusty. change `/etc/lxc/default.conf` to support networking and use `lxc-create -n rubibuntu -t ubuntu -- -r trusty` to create a VM. Change to the VM, using `lxc-attach -n rubibuntu` and setup the environment `apt-get install wget python ipython python-imaging python-serial python-wxgtk2.8` ... no package ia32-libs availabe and no characters as comment

Comment: It seems you just copied the installation instruction, `ia32-libs` no longer a thing since years ago.

Comment: @Emmet Yes, you are right. I've read the INSTALL and copied the extract here. ... As you see in my second post (where I tested it), I don't mentioned it anymore, because Ubuntu Trusty says 'no package available' and it worked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it is a little more tricky, than I thought. But as I have a similar problem on my own, I've just created a solution that works for you, too (tested).
Very helpful to understand all commands is this Blog article: https://blog.simos.info/how-to-easily-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/

- Install snap ans LXD (Linux Container)

  1. `# apt install snapd`
  2. `# apt purge lxd; snap install lxd`
  3. `# lxc init` (In Debian Stretch I need to add /snap/bin/ to $PATH for root manually)
  4. Add **pool as dir**, **no for IPv6** if not needed
  5. `$ echo "root:$UID:1" | sudo tee -a /etc/subuid /etc/subgid`
  6. `$ lxc profile create gui`
  7. `$ wget [....]lxdguiprofile.txt` see https://blog.simos.info/how-to-easily-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/ for details
  8. `$ cat lxdguiprofile.txt | lxc profile edit gui`
- Setup VM

  1. `# adduser [user] lxd` (new login needed, see `id` if you are already joined the group, than /snap/bin should also be available in $PATH)
  2. `$ lxc launch --profile default --profile gui ubuntu:trusty rubiks`
  3. `$ lxc exec rubiks -- sudo --user ubuntu --login`
- Finally use the commands from my fist answer in the VM

  1. `$ sudo apt install python ipython python-imaging python-serial python-wxgtk2.8`
  2. `$ wget http://isle.princip.cz/download/futurocube/sdk_suite/rubiks-futuro-cube.SC1.8.tgz`
  3. `$ tar xfvz rubiks-futuro-cube.SC1.8.tgz`
  4. `$ cd rubiks-futuro-cube`
  5. `$ ./rubiks-futuro-cube`

I've got no cube here, but I'm seeing your application.

If you're done, cleanup the playground (or stop here and keep it as long as you need).

- Clean up

  1. close the application
  2. `$ exit` -> goes back to the physical system
  3. `$ lxc stop rubiks`
  4. `$ lxc delete rubiks`