# Python3.5-tk in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: python, dpkg, dependencies, python3, tkinter

I installed python3.5 and some package like opencv, Tesrflow, keras and etc when my Linux version was 16.04. But after upgrading the Linux version from 16.04 to 18.04, the new version of **python 3.6** has been installed. So, I face with major problem:

Some package and dependencies such as OpenCv, Tensorflow, .. were installed in python3.5, but the major package (**python3-tk**) which is necessary for image processing and GUI is deleted from python3.5 and it works just in python3.6. On the other hand Tensorflow and .. just work in Python3.5. **I run the following command but noting happen**:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

The Error is:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.5-tk
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.5-tk'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.5-tk'
```

How can I install **python3-tk** just for **python3.5** on Ubuntu **18.04**??

Is there any way to remove python3.5 without **lose** the dependencies??

or Can I mount or **share** the dependencies between two version??

Comment: Late welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Hope you already figured out if not, follow the same method in this answer to install old version of python. https://askubuntu.com/a/789327/26246